# How can I simultaneously take pictures from multiple USB webcams?

Tags: photos, webcam

I am looking at using a setup of multiple webcams (5+) to recreate the bullet time effect. However, I have no idea how to simultaneously capture photos from all the webcams hooked up to my computer. How do I do this? I can't have any delay between the pictures; they all have to be taken at the exact same time.

Comment: Final Cut Pro?.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just record videos and synchronize them based on sound or something? You could save frames as images with something like `ffmpeg -i input.mov -r 5 %d.png`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will do everything you need, but [SecuritySpy](http://www.bensoftware.com/securityspy/) is able to capture video from half a dozen cameras or more simultaneously.